# angular service with nested jsonp

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For some reason, the jsonp call in the below angular service is not resolving as a success. It's not the URL. Any ideas why?

```
getDepotInfo : function (depotCode) {

                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var oneDepInfo = {};

   $http.get("data/depotList.json").success(function (data) {
                    some code...


                }).then(function(){

                    $http.jsonp("http://urlhere").success(function (response) {

                            additional code...

                            deferred.resolve(oneDepInfo);

                    })
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            }
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with the response from the server?

Comment: You are mixing the deprecated `.success` style with the correct `.then` promise, but then adding another unnecessary layer of promises from `$q`.

Comment: Show erro in console?

Comment: I think you must add the callback param in url ... `"http://urlhere?callback=JSON_CALLBACK"`. Beware that not all API's return jsonp

Answer (score 0):

Try change as:

**EDIT 1**

```
$http.get("data/depotList.json").then(
    function(){
        $http.jsonp("http://urlhere").success(function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        });
    }, 
    function(error){
        console.error("ERROR: " + error);
    }
);
```

**EDIT 2**

```
$scope.getDepo = function(callback){
    $http.get("data/depotList.json").then(
        function (data) {
            //additional code sucess...
            callback(data);
        },
        function(data){
            //additional code error...
            $scope.getOuther(callback);
        }
    );
};

$scope.getOuther = function(callback){
    $http.jsonp("http://urlhere").then(
        function (data) {
            //additional code sucess...
            console.log("Sucess: " + data);
            callback(data);
        },
        function(data){
            //additional code error...
            console.log("ERROR: " + data);
        }
    );
};

$scope.go = function(){
    $scope.getDepo(function(data){
        console.log("Sucess: " + data);
    });
};
```

Comment: If I replace $http.jsonp with a $http.get and test a url that is not cross-origin, I can receive a success response just fine. I can also test the $http.jsonp call outside of the nested https, and it works fine. It appears there is something wrong with using $http.jsonp within the then callback... The above answers are not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What version of angularjs do you use?

Be careful with success method, in the latest stable version of angular (1.4.7 as I know) the $http promise methods success and error have been deprecated. From angularjs doc:

> **Deprecation Notice**
>
> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then ***these methods will throw $http/legacy error***.

Try to catch the error (with `catch(errorCallback)`) to be sure or just change to `then` method instead of `success`

Comment: none of the suggestions so far have been helpful. Can anyone offer better advice?